# Opening different docker folder in vscode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to develop inside docker running WSL2 Ubuntu using vscode (Using docker desktop).
I am able to open container's folder1 (say) in vscode.
Now I want to open another folder of same container in vscode. But everytime I click on container or folder of a container, it open same folder in vscode. I right clicked on folder and selected remove recent folder and then double clicked on container, it still ends up opening same folder. Where do I specify which folder to open?

[image]

[ref](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/attach-container)